# phpmailer & ajax : file attachment with the mail

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpmailer

I have a working contact form so a user can email me while not having to refresh the page, using ajax.

I'd like my user to have the option to attach a file with his email, but I'm kind of lost as how to process the data with Ajax.

Here is the contact form :

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="/handler.php?ajax=contact">

    <input type="email" name="contact-email" id="contact-email" />

    <select name="contact-category" id="contact-category">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="contact-subject" id="contact-subject" />

    <textarea name="contact-message"></textarea>

    <input type="file" name="contact-attachment" id="contact-attachment" />

    <button class="btn-classic btn-orange"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> send</button>

</form>
```

The ajax function :

```
$(function(contactSubmit) {

    var contactForm = $('#tab-contact #contact-form');
    var contactCallback = $('#tab-contact #contact-callback');

    $(contactForm).submit(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        var contactData = $(contactForm).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(contactForm).attr('action'),
            data: contactData,
        }).done(function(response) {
            $("#contact-callback").addClass("success");
        }).fail(function(data) {
            $("#contact-callback").addClass("fail");
        });

    });


});
```

and the 2 php functions to verify the data and send the mail :

```
<?php

public static function contact() {

    $mail_from_email = filter_var(trim($_POST['contact-email']), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $mail_from_name = 'User1';
    $mail_to_email = 'webmaster@site.com';
    $mail_to_name = 'Webmaster';
    $mail_subject = '['.$_POST['contact-category'].'] '.trim($_POST['contact-subject']);
    $mail_body = trim($_POST['contact-message']);
    $mail_attachment = $_FILES['contact-attachment'];

    $sendMail = action::sendMail($mail_from_email, $mail_from_name, $mail_to_email, $mail_to_name, $mail_subject, $mail_body, $mail_attachment);

}

public static function sendMail($mail_from_email, $mail_from_name, $mail_to_email, $mail_to_name, $mail_subject, $mail_body, $mail_attachment) {

    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                                 // Enable verbose debug output

    $mail->isSMTP();                                        // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = config::get('mail_smtp_host');            // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                 // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = config::get('mail_smtp_username');    // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = config::get('mail_smtp_password');    // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = config::get('mail_smtp_security');  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = config::get('mail_smtp_port');            // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom($mail_to_email, $mail_from_name);
    $mail->addAddress($mail_to_email, $mail_to_name);       // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('');                                  // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo($mail_from_email, $mail_from_name);
    $mail->addCC('');
    $mail->addBCC('');

    $mail->addAttachment($mail_attachment);                 // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('');                               // Optional name
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                    // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = $mail_subject;
    $mail->Body    = $mail_body;
    $mail->AltBody = '';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        return $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}

?>
```

However I've been stuck at step 1 : My php function is unable to retrieve the data from the file input, it seems like ajax isn't sending the informations regarding this input field.
Php returns `Undefined index: contact-attachment`.

Can anyone guide/help me through this ? What is wrong with my current code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You form tag doesn't contain all attributes.

Replace

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="/handler.php?ajax=contact">
```

with

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="/handler.php?ajax=contact" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#contact-form').submit( function( e ) {
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.pathname,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
    return false; 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="/handler.php?ajax=contact" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="email" name="contact-email" id="contact-email" />

    <select name="contact-category" id="contact-category">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="contact-subject" id="contact-subject" />

    <textarea name="contact-message"></textarea>

    <input type="file" name="contact-attachment" id="contact-attachment" />

    <button class="btn-classic btn-orange"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> send</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I fixed it but it still gives me the error: `Undefined index: contact-attachment`

Comment: Replace 
var contactData = $(contactForm).serialize();
with 
var contactData = new FormData(contactForm);

Comment: I am now getting "illegal invocation"

Comment: I have added working fiddle. Please check. Don't forget to change ajax url with yours.

Comment: Allright sorry it took so long I actually got a typo wrong and it took me some time to realize it. It seems to be on the way to work ! The file input is now received by php but the php part must be wrong since the attachment is not sent (array to string conversion in phpmailer regarding the file input) I will go back to phpmailer's manual and update you, thank you again !

Comment: It's now fully working (just followed the manual for the final steps). Thank you !